# What can cause ng-class in AngularJS to append class, rather than remove it?

Tags: angularjs

I've run into some problems in a project that i'm working on - with ng-class, when adding multiple conditions - in some cases, the classes append instead of being removed - according to the condition, example:

```
  <div ng-app ng-controller="LoginController">

     <i class="fa selected" ng-class="{'fa-star':!!isClicked, 'fa-star- 
       o':!isClicked}"></i>
      <button ng-click="isClicked = !isClicked">Click</button>

  </div>
```

What i'm experiencing in that when isClicked is false - the fa-star class remains...the fa-star-o class is being appended, so i'm getting both classes.

I can't recreate the bug, as i said - it occurs somtimes in a project that i'm working on...so i wonder if anyone have exprienced anything like it before.

Here is the same code from my project, here it's working well.
[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/roybarak/0kdz3w85/2/)

Comment: Why do you use _double negation operator - !!_ before `isClicked`?

Comment: True and not undedined, rather than just false

Answer (score 0):

Change `ng-class="{'fa-star':!!isClicked` to `ng-class="{'fa-star':isClicked`

Comment: ,thanks for the quick response, double exclamation point means - true and not undefined...so it's not that...i've also try what you've suggested before...but no luck yet :)